# Why Wordpress query_post is not showing correct posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to query wordpress post by using `query_posts` and trying to save them in an array so that I get retrieve the post from array. This is what I'm doing,

```
$posts= array();
$args = array('posts_per_page' =>3,'cat' => 3 );
$posts[] = query_posts( $args );

global $post;
if ( ! empty($posts) ) :
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);  
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

When I run this script it shows a post which is not in `cat` 3. but if I do `print_r($post)` it shows the correct three posts. Any idea of where I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Why are you declaring global $post and reassign it in the sequence?

Comment: Check if one of those posts are sticky, wordpress has a thing that 'injects' sticky posts inside queries, use `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: You should remove the initial assignment of an empty array to `$posts`, and remove the brackets when assigning the result of `query_posts`. Currently `$posts` is always an array containing a single array with the results.

Comment: Actually I want `$posts` to be in array so that I could get post out of it while using multiple queries

Answer (score 1):

This one should work also [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) is preferred method for secondary queries.

```
global $post;
$posts_args  = array('cat' => 3, 'posts_per_page' => 3);
$posts_query = new WP_Query($posts_args);
$posts_arr   = $posts_query->get_posts();

if ( ! empty($posts_arr) ) :
    foreach ($posts_arr as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: I'm using an array to put the post into an array. I want to query post from an array.

Comment: @user3293145 there you go posts_arr is what you want i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

No need to declare it as an array:

```
global $post;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,'cat' => 3);
$query = query_posts($args);
foreach ($query as $post) {
   setup_postdata($post); 
   the_title();
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: There is a need of declaring it as array because I would then be using multiple queries to get the posts.

Comment: @user3293145 Then you can use multiple loops and `query_posts` or store `$query` into another variable for later use if that's what you want.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use multiple queries but to show the results in one array, because I want to get mixture of posts from multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

Remember that query_posts modifies the main loop, so probably the post that is not from cat = 3 is from the main loop. Try to create a new query with [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

```
$posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=3&cat=3');
global $post;
if (!empty($posts)):
    foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo get_the_title();
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```